# problem while capturing the error of `make`

Tags: perl, makefile

The purpose behind this perl script is to first refactor a `.cpp` file and then compile the whole package. If all goes well then move on to the next file otherwise replace the original file from the `backup` directory, and so on. Following is the perl script for running the `makefile` of a package.

```
@lcpp = `ls *.cpp`; 
chomp(@lcpp);
foreach (@lcpp) {
print "processing file $_ ...";
`cp demac_dir/$_ .`;
if(2 == `make`) {
  print "\n\t\t\tError in the file\n";
  `cp backup/$_ .`;
  print "reverting back to the original file and building the package again";
  `make`;
}
else {#when successfully compiled
  print "successfully compiled the package with file $_";
}
}
```

The script runs until i get a 'refactored' file with compiler errors. The script is unable to capture the error returned by `make` i guess. Or am i missing something.

Comment: Why backticks and not just call [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)?

Comment: ok ... i'm trying system() now

Comment: With this many system calls, though, seems like using perl is overkill. Exchange the first line with `my @lcpp = glob "*.cpp";`, then you get a nice smooth array with no need to chomp it. [File::Copy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Copy) for the copy/move commands. I suspect there's something nice for make as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `system()` to invoke make, you can check whether make succeeded. see `perldoc -f system`:

```
    @args = ("command", "arg1", "arg2");
    system(@args) == 0
         or die "system @args failed: $?"

You can check all the failure possibilities by inspecting $?
like this:

    if ($? == -1) {
        print "failed to execute: $!\n";
    }
    elsif ($? & 127) {
        printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
            ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
    }
    else {
        printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
    }
```

Comment: rite now i'm trying system()... let's see how it goes... thanks for the suggestion

Comment: yeah the system() function is working nicely... I should have asked in SO 3-4 hours ago... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Almost for sure make errors go to STDERR, which is not captured by backticks. Use [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Capture%3a%3aTiny) for easy capture of both output streams.

Comment: i just want that if make is unsuccessful then the script should 'know' and do the needful. Yes you are right the error messages go to 'stderr'

Comment: @Aditya Kumar - I was thinking that you would like to parse the output to see what error happened. If you need just success, checking `$?` is probably fastest way.